# Extract values inside XML

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe

I need to parse the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<revista numero="2226" data="03/09/2013">
  <processo numero="902987089">
    <despachos>
      <despacho codigo="IPAS139"/>
    </despachos>
    <titulares>
      <titular nome-razao-social="AAAAA" pais="BR" uf="PR"/>
    </titulares>
  </processo>
  <processo numero="902812165">
    <despachos>
      <despacho codigo="IPAS029"/>
    </despachos>
    <titulares>
      <titular nome-razao-social="XXXX" pais="BR" uf="SC"/>
    </titulares>
(...)
```

I'm not experienced at all with XML. I'm using `IXMLDocument` in Delphi.

```
LNodeElement := LDocument.ChildNodes.FindNode('revista');
(...)
for I := 0 to LNodeElement.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
(...)
```

My question is how can I reach the `numero` attribute value inside the `<processo>` tag? But if a kind soul could share a small example it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For instance this way:

```
uses
  XMLDoc, XMLIntf;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  NumberAttr: IXMLNode;
  XMLDocument: IXMLDocument;
  ProcessNodes: IXMLNodeList;
begin
  // load an XML file
  XMLDocument := LoadXMLDocument('c:\File.xml');
  // take the list of all "revista/processo" nodes
  ProcessNodes := XMLDocument.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
  // and iterate that "processo" node collection
  for I := 0 to ProcessNodes.Count - 1 do
  begin
    // try to find the "numero" attribute for currently iterated "processo" node
    NumberAttr := ProcessNodes[I].AttributeNodes.FindNode('numero');
    // if the "numero" attribute was found, show its value (or do something else)
    if Assigned(NumberAttr) then
      ShowMessage(NumberAttr.Text);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Wait, but this is wrong, isn't it ? You were going to get the value of `<revista>` tag didn't you ? I'm iterating `<processo>` tags... You're missing the most important word in the sentence *how can I reach the "numero" value inside the tag*, but which tag is missing there. The `numero` attribute is in in both tags, in `<revista>` as well as `<processo>` tags.

Comment: It's right. I need the "numero" inside <processo>. The first isn't needed.

Comment: Ah sorry, it was in the question, [`just hidden`](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/cf3a1216-3828-4d12-a14c-38d0f1dcff8b/view-source) because it was an unquoted tag. Well, I was quite lucky this time :-)

Comment: @MiguelE: I know you already accepted the answer, but another thing you could do is to write a XSD file and use the Delphi XML Data binder wizard to generate an utility unit that handles all the intrincacies of the XML. Writing a XSD file is easy and it´s very well explained in [link](http://www.w3schools.com). By doing that your application´s code will be much simpler.

Comment: @Tlama - If I wanted to get the "codigo" value from despacho, how can I do it? I'm trying (inside the for): DespachosNodes:= ProcessNodes[i].ChildNodes;
    if DespachosNodes.Count > 0 then
    begin
       CodigoAttr:= DespachosNodes[0].AttributeNodes.FindNode('codigo');
       if Assigned(CodigoAttr) then
          s:= s+ '  '+ CodigoAttr.Text;
    end; , but I'm missing something...

Comment: You need to go one level deeper. You're trying to read the `codigo` attribute in the `<despachos>` node, not in `<despacho>`. You can do it also with `FindNode` as you shown in your question (look at [`this example`](http://pastebin.com/q50F1zeU)). I've used that node list here just because I was going to iterate all `<processo>` nodes which are of the same level.